# How to load an image from an edited variable ?

Tags: php, variables, replace, edit, src

Hello and sorry for the noobie question
Let's say i have a variable with value url

```
<input type="text" name="link">
```

Which submits the following link :

```
domain.com/profile/deCKfkiriCJFff
```

Since the link above is not a valid img src i would like to display an image with the same source but with one slight change :

```
domain.com/profile/images/deCKfkiriCJFff
```

^ valid image link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$domain = 'domain.com/profile/deCKfkiriCJFff';
$exploded = explode('profile', $domain);
$validUrl =  $exploded[0].'profile/images'.$exploded[1];
echo $validUrl;
```